# Can I prevent the updated script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm doing a Exam on a Web page works descending in advance so that if the time is up in question closes the question was the piece successfully through the following function

```
 <script>
     function countdown() { 
        > window.location.href="@Url.Action("TimeOver", "Answers"} )";
        > } 
       setTimeout(function () { countdown(); }, 1000); 
 </script>
```

The bad thing is that when you refresh the page again restores the interim as if time did not end Can I bypass it, or is it inevitable fate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no unless your users are authenticated.

If they are authenticated then you need to persist the timestamp that they first requested the question in your database. Disable browser caching and check for an existing timestamp on page load and check it against the time the answer is submitted. Anything done client side is not reliable, although usually delivers a better UX.

You could implement it using cookies and javascript if it's not mission critical, although this is easily bypassed by a power user, let alone a skilled attacker.